multi-auth in laravel version 11 with filament
I want to practice creating an ecommerce website using laravel 11 and filament for the admin dashboard. then I want to login and register using jetsream, but I have a problem when the user has logged in it still has access to the admin dashboard where I don't want that to happen. How do I create multi-auth?
I want to know how to create the multi-auth feature and how to configure/setup if using a pakage like spatie or whatever it is that can be used to create a multi-auth feature.

Please show your code for the authentication process.
